# Missing MWS subscription notifications pushed to SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-mws

It appears that we aren't getting all AnyOfferChanged notifications on an Amazon SQS. Many are arriving in the queue, but a manual analysis is showing that many are also just going missing.

Is there any way to query MWS to see a list of notifications or even a simple count for the day?

Any common causes for losing MWS subscription notifications sent to SQS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to query the SQS system.  They are just messages in a queue and you read them, process them, and then delete them.  We have been using the AnyOfferChanged notifications for about a year and just have to trust that they work.  If you're sure that the criteria is met (a product you sell, and a price changes in the top 20 offers, new or used) and there is not message in the queue for it, the I would open a ticket with Seller Central.  We have seen that it is near-real time that an SQS notification arrives for one of our product price changes.

To get a count for the day, you'd just have to read messages from your queue starting at a certain point, add +1 to a count variable for each message, delete them from the queue, and then look at the counter after 24 hours.  Best I can think of.